How exactly to do these exercises for hypertension? Are the effects additive?
This paper published in British Journal of Sport Medicine looked into effect of different exercises titled - "Exercise training and resting blood pressure: a large-scale pairwise and network meta-analysis of randomized controlled trials"
It concluded that the following exercises have the most effect on blood pressure



Sl.No
Exercise
sBP Reduction
dBP Reduction




1
Isometric Wall Squat
10.47
5.33


2
Isometric Leg Extension
10.05
4.23


3
Isometric Handgrip
7.10
3.46


4
Cycling
6.88
3.22


5
Running
6.83
5.67



I want to know two things,

How exactly to do these exercises? Like how many times? For how long for the results? For eg: It says running, what does that mean? Medium pace running? Jogging? How far or how long? Should we use any weight on legs while doing leg extensions?

Are the effects additive of these different exercises? I think except handgrip all other exercises are training similar muscles, so to get the max benefit which all exercises can be done? If everything is done will the effects be additive?


Link: Exercise training and resting blood pressure: a large-scale pairwise and network meta-analysis of randomized controlled trials

This is a meta analysis. To get the exact methodology, you'll need to read through the papers cited.

From the full text of the paper:

[Isometric exercise training] programmes commonly employ protocols of 4×2min contractions, separated by 1–4min rest intervals, performed three times a week. [Isometric handgrip] is often prescribed at 30% maximum voluntary contraction, while [isometric wall squat] and [isometric leg extension] protocols are typically performed at 95% of the peak heart rate achieved during a laboratory-based maximal incremental isometric exercise test. The [isometric wall squat] may also be prescribed using a self-selected wall squat, with a knee joint angle that would elicit a rate of perceived exertion (RPE) of 3.5–4.5/10 for bout 1; RPE 5–6/10 for bout 2; RPE of 6.5–7.5/10 for bout 3 and RPE of 8–9/10 for bout 4.

As for whether the effects are additive, they're likely only partially additive. For example, aerobic training was found to cause an average 4.49/2.53mm Hg reduction, dynamic resistance training was found to cause an average 4.55/3.04mm Hg reduction, but combined aerobic and resistance training only caused an average 6.04/2.54mm Hg reduction, rather than the 9.04/5.57mm Hg reduction that you'd expect if they were perfectly additive.

I'd argue that we should say: they are not additive by proof given in the paper (and noted by you).
